# Updating from core 8.7.9 to 8.8.0

Tags: updating, composer

I'm running into an issue when updating to Drupal core 8.8.0. I've removed both the vendor folder and the composer.lock file, as per instructions on this link 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2700999#s-special-considerations-for-upgrading-to-drupal-880-and-later

I run `composer require drupal/core-recommended:^8.8 --update-with-dependencies`
and I get the following:

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.0-rc1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.0-beta2
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.0-beta1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.0-beta1
    - Installation request for acquia/lightning 4.0.4 -> satisfiable by acquia/lightning[4.0.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.8.0-alpha1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 8.9.x-dev
    - acquia/lightning 4.0.4 requires drupal/claro ^1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/claro[1.x-dev, 1.0.0-beta1, 1.0.0-alpha5, 1.0.0-alpha4, 1.0.0-alpha3, 1.0.0-alpha2, 1.0.0-alpha1].
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|don't install drupal/claro 1.x-dev
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|don't install drupal/claro 1.0.0-beta1
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|don't install drupal/claro 1.0.0-alpha5
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|don't install drupal/claro 1.0.0-alpha4
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|don't install drupal/claro 1.0.0-alpha3
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|don't install drupal/claro 1.0.0-alpha2
    - don't install drupal/core 8.8.x-dev|don't install drupal/claro 1.0.0-alpha1
    - Installation request for drupal/core ^8.8.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.8.0, 8.8.0-alpha1, 8.8.0-beta1, 8.8.0-rc1, 8.8.1, 8.8.2, 8.8.3, 8.8.4, 8.8.5, 8.8.x-dev, 8.9.0-beta1, 8.9.0-beta2, 8.9.x-dev].
```

At this point, running `composer prohibits drupal/core:8.8.0` won't work because I removed `drupal/core` as per instructions in the link above.

I can successfully update to 8.7.13, so maybe I can settle for that for now. But our team wants to be ready for Drupal 9 and upgrading to 8.8 will make that transition easier, I hear.

Should I update to 8.7.13 first, before attempting to upgrade to 8.8?

**EDIT** 
I'm able to update to Drupal 8.8 by removing the vendor folder and composer.lock and removing acquia/lightning. I reinstalled acquia/lightning after Drupal core was added.
I am now running into issues when running drush dbupdate.

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong, please follow the [Updating Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer) documentation.

Comment: I have tried just running composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies. I don't get any errors but it stays at 8.7.9

Comment: And `rm composer.lock && rm -rf vendor/ && composer install` gives you what?

Comment: It looks like the issue might be with acquia lightning.

Comment: @leymannx, I just tried it and it gave me the same result as above.

Comment: @mradcliffe I removed acquia/lightning from composer.json and ran the update again. It worked, but now I'm debugging some database errors that came out when I ran drush dbupdate.

Answer (score 1):

In your `composer.json` file (found in the root of your drupal site) find the line `"drupal/core": "x.xx"` and change it to `"drupal/core": "~8.8"` and then run `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies`

Also, don't forget to run your database updates after! (run `drush updb` or go to `your-drupal-site.com/update.php`)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it suggested I remove acquia/lightning from my composer.json file. I ran the update again and it worked in composer, but now there are database problems being encountered.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you're using `acquia/lightning` which is not a dependency from core but the other way around, so running that command with the dependencies flag will not work.

Run the command as follows:

```
$ composer update drupal/core acquia/lightning --with-dependencies
```

This will tell composer to update both Core and Lightning. Note, this is still constrained to having your `composer.json` not fixed to a specific version, so ensure they are specified with either a `^` or `~` accordingly.

Also note that you can still face individual constraints that need updating as dependencies from Lightning itself. If that happens, just include those packages to your update command.

You can also refer to https://github.com/acquia/lightning/releases for the release notes, as the maintainers usually include the required commands for you as per your version of Core accordingly.

**Final note:** never remove your `composer.lock` file and also never run `composer update` without any package specified, as that will update all packages.